# Select single value using Linq to XML

Tags: linq-to-xml

My brain isnt working today. How can I select the "IDValue" which only occurs once in an xml file like below?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
 <result>
<Property>
  <PropertyID>
    <Identification>
      <IDValue>8361</IDValue>
      <OrganizationName>Lynd Company</OrganizationName>
    </Identification>
  </PropertyID>
</Property>
  </result>
</response>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("pathtoXml");
var value = doc.Descendants("IDValue").SingleOrDefault().Value;
```